# Animated (cartoon) space movie from the eighties, possibly earlier

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This was intended for kids; I remember it being a group of really young persons. I remember stuff but not enough to explain in detail.

I think there was some kind of orbs on their ship, and like I said, this must have been meant for young kids. I don't think it was done in manga style movie ,nor did it have any scary monsters as far as I remember. I've been trying to find this for a while, but with not much content to go on it’s really hard to find.

I must have seen it around  1984–85 ,but it probably wasn't brand new. I saw it on Swedish television or a rented VHS tape. It was a upbeat movie.

Comment: What did the orbs do for them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you describe the ship at all?  What did the orbs do?  How many characters were there, and how did they interact with the orbs?  What was driving the plot?

Comment: So long ago i only remember orbs on rods sticking out from the ship. It was some kknd of journey but not a sad or gloomy one but a jolly one. Been trying to remember more about this, the only thing im sure of is that it was for kids, and that id recognize the ship or perhaps characters. Think it was 3-5 main characters with one being a pet perhaps

Comment: I think i can remember it was called a space adventure or somethkng like that but in swedish

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a ship with orbs and the space, made me think of [Bobobobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobobobs), a less known Spanish cartoon for children.
Also see [here](https://www.filmaffinity.com/en/film817871.html)

It is about a group of bearded sailors (I really have no clue how to describe them better... but in the crew there were also a kid, whose best friend who was a kind of strange floating creature and also a wizard) who travel through the space to reach a planet where they went to know there were people in distress, I remember they were besieged by dinosaurs or something similar.

In order to reach that planet, they travel through the space with a spherical ship with orbs, this is an image

[image])

Comment: Thanks. Its not that one though. It should be more spaceshippy spaceships and a young crew